# Прижать Spinner влево в Tollbar'e android

Tags: android, menu

Нужно реализовать переключение между фрагментами с помощью BottomAppBar и Spinner'a в одном из фрагментов

Сейчас выглядит так
[image: 123]

А нужно вот так
[image: 1324]

Добавляю из фрагмента так:
**DashboardFragment.java**

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment1, menu);
   super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Пробовал добавлять так, тогда прижат справа, но не исчезает при переходе на другую вкладку из BottomAppBar

```
ActionBar toolbar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
toolbar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
toolbar.setCustomView(R.menu.spiner);
```

Answer (score 0):

В разметке:

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:navigationIcon="@null">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--     your spinner       -->
        <Spinner
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/spinner_entries"
            android:theme="@style/SpinnerTheme" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня еще как я и писал есть bottomAppBar и нужно чтоб только в одном фрагменте был спиннер

Comment: Так сделайте в каждом  фрагмете свой Toolbar или же в активити управлять видимостью спиннера. Т.е. активити отслеживает клики на BottomNavigationView (на скрине именно он) и в зависимости от позиции клика управляет видимость виджетов из тулбара. Я думаю вариант с тулбаром в каждом фрагменте проще

Comment: Делаю свой Toolbar в каждом фрагмете, добавляю из onCreateView в фрагменте ```View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard,container,true);
        androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity)getActivity();
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);``` но ToolBar не появляется

Comment: Разобрался с добавлением toolBar'ов, можно ли как то избавится от мерцания при переключении?

Comment: Если тулбар размещён в фрагменте, то его не нужно подключать как supportActionBar. Тулбар можно использовать как обычное View. Просто в разметке оставить место для него и разместить его.

Comment: @noctual а где расположен тулбар ? и как он переключается ? Не совсем понял.

Comment: ToolBar в разметке фрагмента, фрагменты переключаются через BottomNavigationView.

Comment: @noctual, нужно смотреть разметку и код переключения фрагментов, так вообще не понимаю. Может анимация стоит в beginTransaction().setTransition(XXX). Так собрал проект на BottomNav с тулбаром - всё нормально.